# Motion error: Sometimes Permission denied

Tags: motion

I have motion installed and it works correct most of the time. But sometimes it gives me this errors:

```
[1:ml1] [NTC] [EVT] [May 03 09:48:24] event_new_video Source FPS 2
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [May 03 09:48:24] motion_detected: Motion detected - starting event 1
[1:ml1] [ERR] [ALL] [May 03 09:48:24] myfopen: Error opening file /home/pi/Telegram_Python/Pictures/01-20200503094824-01.jpg with mode w: Permission denied
[1:ml1] [ERR] [ALL] [May 03 09:48:24] put_picture: Can't write picture to file /home/pi/Telegram_Python/Pictures/01-20200503094824-01.jpg - check access rights to target directory
```

Thread is going to finish due to this fatal error: Permission denied

I understand the problem and does it says I have right problems with this directory, but what I don't understand ist that a few minutes before, there are no problems.

```
[1:ml1] [NTC] [EVT] [May 03 08:57:17] event_new_video Source FPS 2
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [May 03 08:57:17] motion_detected: Motion detected - starting event 4
[1:ml1] [NTC] [EVT] [May 03 08:57:17] event_newfile: File of type 1 saved to: /home/pi/Telegram_Python/Pictures/04-20200503085717-01.jpg
```

Comment: Are you sure you have only one instance of Motion running ? Normally it runs as user `motion` and shouldn't have access to `/home/pi` unless you granted permission to that directory or changed the Motion settings in the configuration file.

Comment: How can I check, if I have multiple instances running? I think this is my problem